# Opera SVG bug when scrolling

Tags: html, css, browser, svg, opera

I designed a section with social links on my website. The SVG icons are used as background images. Everything works fine except in Opera (latest release, no beta). When I scroll down, the icons are being "cut". Does anyone of you have the same problem?

Any recommendation how to fix that?

Comment: Please post a screenshot and/or link to your site, along with the specific version of Opera you are using.  ("Latest release" doesn't mean much a week from today.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an ancient bug of [svg background + rounded corners](http://my.opera.com/c69/blog/svg-repaint-bug-case-study).

**Workaround**: do not use rounded corners on same element with svg background.

Comment: That's bug CORE-7377 probably.

Comment: @ErikDahlström you know, mere mortals cannot confirm or deny that - because Opera's bug tracker is non-public ;)